# Modifying a byte with bash, dd isn't working

Tags: bash, dd

I'm trying to modify a byte with bash,

So I will write the bytes before the offset, then the byte to modify, and the rest of the file.

But the following script doesn't work as expected

Anyone please take a look? Couldn't figure out which part is wrong

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/etc/passwd
out=passwd.mod
offset=0x5

dd if="$file" of="$out" conv=notrunc bs=1 count=$(($offset - 1))
printf '\x41' | dd of="$out" conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$(($offset))
dd if="$file" of="$out" conv=notrunc bs=1 skip=$(($offset + 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, I believe that this will work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=passwd.orig
out=passwd.mod
offset=0x5

dd if="$file" of="$out" conv=notrunc bs=1 count=$(($offset))
printf '\x41' | dd of="$out" conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$(($offset))
dd if="$file" of="$out" conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$((offset+1)) skip=$(($offset + 1))
```

You do need both `seek` to place the "writing head" at the correct position and `skip` to avoid those bytes from being written (again) to the output.

---

#### Better

If all you need to do is to change (replace) a byte, you can do that directly in a copy of the file, as this simple (and POSIX) pair of commands will do:

```
#!/bin/sh

file=passwd.orig      out=passwd.mod         offset=0x05

cp "$file" "$out"
printf '\x41' | dd of="$out" conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$(($offset))
```

If you want to "insert" a byte, you do need the commands above but with some changes to the offsets. Please ask if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `seek` in the last command:

```
dd if="$file" of="$out"  \
  conv=notrunc           \
  bs=1                   \
  skip="$((offset + 1))" \
  seek="$((offset + 1))"
```

`skip=n` skips n input block from input file before copying, `seek=n` skips n input block of output file before copying. You need both of them to correctly the writing offset.

Comment: And a correct `count` of `$offset` in the first command (not $offset -1 ).

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1) `dd if="$file" of="$out"` seems to overwrite *$out* at some point.
2) Even allowing for that, the *count=*, *skip=*, & *seek=* logic loses
   a byte somewhere in there.

Instead try something like this:

```
file=/etc/passwd
out=passwd.mod
offset=0x5

dd if="$file" of="$out" conv=notrunc bs=1 count=$offset
printf '\x41' >> $out
dd if="$file"  conv=notrunc bs=1 skip=$(($offset + 1)) >> $out
```

Adjust *$offset* give or take a few as needed -- since it was off by one before it's only my guess.